# how to write this specific MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to create a MySQL query, for my messaging thread (i.e. sender/recipient).

I have a table with a field (msg_id = unique 6 digit id like 123456). This (msg_id) field may have lots of rows (for each msg reply) where each row would have the same (msg_id) like a thread. So, lets say bob started messaging fred thus the thread in table would be something like (crude example just to illustrate point):-

```
+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------+
| msg_id  | sender_email              | recipient_email          | sender_msg             | cur_date   | cur_time |
+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------+
| 3189855 | bob@hotmail.com           | fred@yahoo.com           | hi fred, how are you?  | 2013-03-10 | 17:12:18 |
| 3189855 | fred@yahoo.com            | bob@hotmail.com          | hi bob, I am great     | 2013-03-10 | 17:15:20 |
| 3189855 | bob@hotmail.com           | fred@yahoo.com           | hi fred, good to hear  | 2013-03-10 | 17:20:10
| 6749672 | jenny@barclay.cc          | fred@yahoo.com           | some other message     | 2013-03-10 | 14:52:49 |
+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------+
```

When displaying either bobs or freds email inbox's I want to display each unique (msg_id) by latest (cur_date, cur_time) so the newest msg/msg reply goes top of inbox list.

So, lets focus on Freds mailbox as Fred has most messages. I want my query to display the following result when outputting inbox emails:

```
+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------+
| msg_id  | sender_email              | recipient_email          | sender_msg             | cur_date   | cur_time |
+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------+
| 3189855 | bob@hotmail.com           | fred@yahoo.com           | hi fred, good to hear  | 2013-03-10 | 17:20:10 |
| 6749672 | jenny@barclay.cc          | fred@yahoo.com           | some other message     | 2013-03-10 | 14:52:49 |
+---------+---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------+----------+
```

So, the query gets each unique (msg_id) and for each unique (msg_id) it gets the last row (i.e. being the last msg in thread sent which works out to the latest msg sent). If that makes sense. My question is therefore how would I generate this SQL query to give above result. My idea is below but does not work:-

```
SELECT * FROM inbox_table WHERE (recipient_email='fred@yahoo.com' AND ORDER BY cur_date DESC, cur_time DESC) GROUP BY msg_id ORDER BY cur_date DESC, cur_time DESC;
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated and I hope I explained this well.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you just need to add quotes around the strings, and the `ORDER BY` clause needs to be in the end, and only one time:

```
SELECT * FROM inbox_table WHERE 
   recipient_email='fred@yahoo.com' 
   GROUP BY msg_id ORDER BY cur_date DESC, cur_time DESC;
```

It might make sense to add an aggregate function to the `SELECT` clause, for example `COUNT`, so you also know how many messages are in the thread:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(msg_id) FROM inbox_table WHERE 
   recipient_email='fred@yahoo.com' 
   GROUP BY msg_id ORDER BY cur_date DESC, cur_time DESC;
```

Finally, I'd advise to change the name `msg_id` into `thread_id`, as it covers the meaning a lot better.

If you want the newest record by time, use this:

```
 SELECT *,MAX(CONCAT(cur_date,' ',cur_time)) FROM inbox_table WHERE 
   recipient_email='fred@yahoo.com' 
   GROUP BY msg_id
```

Comment: hi @Bart, that still does not appear to be getting the last row for msg_id (3189855) still just gets the first row for msg_id (3189855) ?

Comment: In fact, it returns a undefined record, add a `MAX(cur_date)` to the `SELECT` query to get the record you want. You can then also drop the `ORDER BY` clause. You actually want the `MAX` of both date and time. They should be in one column to do that correctly.

Comment: tried adding MAX(cur_date), MAX(cur_time) into SELECT and dropping ORDER By at the end, but still does not appear to be getting the last row for msg_id (3189855)(at 17:20:10) and just gets the first row for msg_id (3189855)(at 17:12:18) ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You have to concat date and time to get a single timestamp and take that `MAX`.

Comment: thanks but still no joy using, your CONCAT in SELECT. Just to clarify I want to display each unique separate msg_id in order of newest cur_date/cur_time but for each unique (msg_id) I want to display the last row in each (msg_id), not the first row.

Comment: Then use `MIN` instead of `MAX`.

Comment: still no luck, tried MIN instead of MAX but still for some reason keeps getting the first row for msg_id (3189855)(at 17:12:18) not the last row for msg_id (3189855)(at 17:12:18). Not sure if this logic can actually be applied to an SQL query

Comment: Apologies, you were correct @Bart using MAX(cur_date), MAX(cur_time) did work and has solved the issue. Best answer awarded, thanks for all your help here.

Comment: Be careful, you will introduce bugs. If you have a record with a later time on an earlier date, it will go wrong (check it)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d2a1/9/0), basically, you didn't quote your string and the parentheses in `WHERE` are unnecessary.

Comment: yes, but the query still does not appear to be getting the last row for msg_id (3189855)(at 17:20:10) and just gets the first row for msg_id (3189855)(at 17:12:18) ?

Comment: Why are you separating cur_date and cur_time?

Comment: I designed it as 2 separate fields, rather than 1. Should it make a difference to the query?

Comment: I know you *designed it as 2 separate fields*, but why did you do this?

Comment: just did so, I could use php function to insert into db fields in correct format ($current_date=date("Y-m-d");) and ($time=date("H:i:s");) into cur_date and cur_time and if I wanted to say search just time, I could rather than both date/time if were together in same field